# How to give my telephone number?

Tags: sentence-structure

Some one asked me for my telephone number, but I am confused about what the correct response should be:

> You can call me at XXX

or

> You can reach me at XXX.

Can anyone explain the difference between these two sentences?

Comment: The correct way is either by using "on" or "at" depending on location.  As @JohnFeltz says, we in Britain would use "on" and in the US, they would use "at"

Comment: However using either would be understood on both sides of the Atlantic.

Answer (score 2):

> Its ###-###-####
>
> My (mobile) number is ###-###-#####
>
> The best place to call/get/reach me is  ###-###-#####
>
> You can call/get/reach me at/on  ###-###-#####

Of course, nowadays the easiest way to give someone your number is to just call or text their phone, that way they have the record and don't have to transcribe.

> What's your number?  I'll text you.